# XSLT: How to select only the text that appears before a particular nested tag without selecting the text that appears after the tag?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I am new in xslt.
My xml code is:

```
        <tag1>
          text1
          <nestedTag Id="text2" /> 
          text3
        </tag1>
```

And I want to receive this output:

**text1 text2 text3**

I write two templates:

```
  <xsl:template match="tag1">
     <b>
      <xsl:apply-templates select = "nestedTag" />
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
     </b>
  </xsl:template>


  <xsl:template match="nestedTag">
    <xsl:value-of select="@Id"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

But I get this:

**text2 text1 text3**

My question is: how to separate between text1 and text3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `tag1` element has three child nodes, a text node, an element node and a text node. The first text node in general can be selected with `text()[1]`, the first child node in general with `node()[1]`.

But in the context of your sample and with XSLT it suffices to replace

```
  <xsl:apply-templates select = "nestedTag" />
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
```

with

```
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
```

as that will process all child nodes and the built-in templates for text nodes will output them.

Comment: thanks! Your answer solved the specific problem,
**but mainly contributed to my understanding of the concept of how the XSLT works** (as I said I'm new to the field)